# Opencv Python VIDEOSTAB class

Tags: python, opencv, video, camera, image-stabilization

I need to implement a stabilization functionality to my opencv project. There is a videostab class, but it is only described for c++ (http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/d50/group__videostab.html). Does anyone know how to use it in Python? I am going to stabilize live video feed by the way.

Answer (score 0):

There are no Python bindings yet. You cannot use the class in Python at the moment.

Comment: Is this still true?  I see videostab when I do dir(cv2).

Comment: Since you checked today, and I 18 months ago, I take your answer as correct.

Comment: @headdab what is the name? I see no videostab even with `[x for x in dir(cv) if 'stab' in x]` for opencv 4.0

Comment: I checked a docker version of opencv 3.0 (harshjv/opencv3python) and my local install of opencv 4.0 and I see it in both.  Try ```help(cv2.videostab)``` from python, for example.  Note that I have never tried to use this function.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, `pip3 install opencv-python` gives version 4.2.0.34 currently but that does not include videostab.

Comment: you can use `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python` to get more classes but the videostab classes and routines appear unavailable